# Slideshow effect with Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

When some prop in my component changes in framer motion, I would like to fade that property out, then fade the "new" property value in?

Here's the timeline of the animation as I imagine it:

- 0: Prop Value Changes, old value start to fade out
- .5: New value visible
- 1: New value finishes fading in

But the only way I see to do this with framer is to use Timeouts. Is there some way other than using timeouts to achieve this effect?

## [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-slide-effect-kddel?file=/src/App.tsx:0-806)

```js
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  const [anim, setAnim] = useState("in");
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
      setAnim("in");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setAnim("out");
      }, 500);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const variants = {
    out: {
      opacity: 0
    },
    in: {
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        duration: 0.5
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <motion.div
      animate={anim}
      variants={variants}
      className="App"
      style={{ fontSize: 100 }}
    >
      {seconds}
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [AnimatePresence](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/).

Wrap your `motion.div` with an `AnimatePresence` tag, and use the `seconds` as a unique key for your div. The changing key will trigger `AnimatePresence` to animate the div in and out each time it changes (because new key means it's a different element).

To get this to work, you'll need to define your animations on the `initial`, `animate`, and `exit` props.

You'll also want to be sure to set the `exitBeforeEnter` prop on `AnimatePresence` so the fade out animation completes before the fade in starts.

[**Sandbox Example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-slide-effect-forked-klkzz?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
export default function App() {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((seconds) => seconds + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);


  return (
    <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
      <motion.div
        initial={{opacity:0}}
        animate = {{opacity: 1, transition:{duration: 0.5}}}
        exit={{opacity: 0 }}
        
        className="App"
        style={{ fontSize: 100 }}
        key={seconds}
      >
        {seconds}
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}
```

Comment: Now that `exitBeforeEnter` is deprecated, it can be replaced with `mode="wait"`: